# google drive api - 'await' has no effect on this expression

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

I have seen countless tutorials online with almost identical code to mine simply putting await infront of the google drive call.

Yet any google call i try add 'await' infront of i get the error:

```
'await' has no effect on this type of expression
```

The code DOES RUN SUCCESSFULLY, but we are getting race conditions because the await is not being respected.

Sample Code

```
// Initialize a service account with the key file and scope needed.
// Use it for or Google Drive authorization.
const KEYFILEPATH = 'credentials.json';
const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'];
const gal = require('google-auth-library');
const { google } = require('googleapis');
const auth = new gal.GoogleAuth({
  keyFile: KEYFILEPATH,
  scopes: SCOPES
});
const drive = google.drive({ version: "v3", auth });


//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//
async function writeFileFromPath(srcPath, dstFolderId, ext, fileName) {

    run().catch(console.error.bind(console));

    async function run() {
        try{



    console.log("Using File Path: ",srcPath);


  if (fileName == '') {
    fileName = srcPath.match(/[\w()-.]+\.[\w]+/g)[0];  // Extract just the filename
  }

  console.log("Using File Name: ",fileName);

  if (ext == '') {
    ext = fileName.match(/[\w]+$/g)[0];
  }

  let mimeType = mimeTypes[ext];

  if (mimeType == '') {
    mimeType = 'text/plain';
  }

  console.log("Using MIME Type: ",mimeType);

  let fileMeta = {
    'name': fileName,
    'parents': [dstFolderId]
  };

  let media = {
    mimeType: mimeType,
    body: fs.createReadStream(srcPath)
  };

// This await does not actually work and code runs ignoring it
  let driveResp =  await drive.files.create({
    supportsTeamDrives: true,
    resource: fileMeta,
    media: media,
    fields: 'id'
  });

  //console.log("Write Call Resp: ",driveResp);
  let fileCreated = false;

  if(typeof driveResp.data !== "undefined"){
    if(typeof driveResp.data.id !== "undefined"){
        console.log(`Created file with id: ${driveResp.data.id}`)
        fileCreated = true;
        return({ status: 200, statusText: `Created file with id: ${driveResp.data.id}` });
    }
  }
  if(!fileCreated){
    console.log(`Failed to create file: ${driveResp}`)
    return({ status: 400, statusText: `File was not created: ${driveResp}` });
  }


} catch (e){
    logger.addLog("googleDrive", "alert", "Unhandled Err: " + e);
    console.log("writeFileFromPath Error Caught: ",e.message);
    return(e.message)
}

    }

};
```

Comment: `await` waits for a promise to resolve - whatever `drive.files.create` is, it does NOT return a promise

Comment: if you `let driveResp = drive.files.create({......})`, i.e. without the `await`, and `console.log(driveResp)` is it a Promise

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure what i did to remedy the issue, but this is a working example thank you for the suggestions guys hope this helps someone else

```
async function writeFileFromPath(srcPath, dstFolderId, ext, fileName) {

  
try{



    console.log("Using File Path: ",srcPath);

    // if no ext passed in, try to parse from the file (multer does not add ext to files it saves so need this)
    if (fileName == '') {
    fileName = srcPath.match(/[\w()-.]+\.[\w]+/g)[0];  // Extract just the filename
    }

    console.log("Using File Name: ",fileName);

    // if no ext passed in, try to parse from the file (multer does not add ext to files it saves so need this)
    if (ext == '') {
    ext = fileName.match(/[\w]+$/g)[0];
    }

    let mimeType = mimeTypes[ext];

    if (mimeType == '') {
    mimeType = 'text/plain';
    }

    console.log("Using MIME Type: ",mimeType);

    let fileMeta = {
    'name': fileName,
    'parents': [dstFolderId]
    };

    let media = {
    mimeType: mimeType,
    body: fs.createReadStream(srcPath)
    };

    //This await claims it does not work but it does, if you remove call will fail every time
    let driveResp = await drive.files.create({
    supportsTeamDrives: true,
    resource: fileMeta,
    media: media,
    fields: 'id'
    });



        function processResponse(driveResp){
        //console.log("DRIVE RESP DATA: ",driveResp)
        let fileCreated = false;

        if(typeof driveResp.data !== "undefined"){

            if(typeof driveResp.data.id !== "undefined"){
                
            console.log(`Created file with id: ${driveResp.data.id}`)
            fileCreated = true;

            return({ status: 200, statusText: `Created file with id: ${driveResp.data.id}` });

            }

        }

        if(!fileCreated){

        console.log(`Failed to create file: ${driveResp}`)
        
        return({ status: 400, statusText: `File was not created: ${driveResp}` });

        }

        }

    return(processResponse(driveResp));

} catch (e){

    logger.addLog("googleDrive", "alert", "Unhandled Err: " + e);
    console.log("writeFileFromPath Error Caught: ",e.message);

    return(e.message);

}


};
```

Comment: What you did was remove the internally defined “run” function, so now you’re returning a promise. The callers await this, and it works, same as my suggestion, though dispensing with the superfluous function.

Answer (score 0):

You might be getting the impression that the `create` function isn't awaited because the containing function at the top doesn't `await` `run`.

If the caller expects to `await writeFileFromPath`, it will be awaiting null (maybe you've attributed the warning to the wrong source line), and things that are expected begin sequentially after the google-drive create will begin right away.

```
async function writeFileFromPath(srcPath, dstFolderId, ext, fileName) {
  return await run().catch(console.error.bind(console));

  async function run() {
    // etc
```